# How to better find item in linked list and move it to front

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to write a method `findMove(E e)` which takes an element `e` and checks if it exists in the linked list.  If so, the function moves the element to the front of the linked list and returns `true`.  Otherwise, it does nothing and returns `false`.  My code so far is below.

```
public boolean findMove(E e) {
    Node previous=head;
    Node current=head;
    while(current !=null){
        if(e.equals(current.item)){ // item has been found
            previous.next=current.next;
            current.next=head;
            head=current;
            return true;
        }
        previous = current;
        current=current.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code works as expected, however I want to go the extra mile and re-write this code so that I do not create any new nodes.  As it stands currently, I am adding a previous and current node.

My question is, is there a way to re-write this code so that I do not create any new nodes?

Comment: Where does the code create the new Node you are worried about?

Comment: You're not creating any new `Node` instances in this code.

Comment: @NormR, the new nodes are called `previous` and `current`, and they are created on line 2 and 3 of that code block.

Comment: @OmarN Those aren't new nodes, they are just references to existing nodes.

Comment: @AndyTurner, arn't `previous` and `current` new nodes?

Comment: nope...  u didn't use the word `new`

Comment: @AndyTurner, oh, I understand now.  That clears it all up.  Thank you!  If you want to answer the question, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @OmarN no. A new Node would involve invoking the constructor, using `new Node(....)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no new Node instances being created in this code.

```
Node previous=head;
Node current=head;
```

These are simply references to existing nodes. Creating a new Node would involve invoking a constructor of `Node`:

```
Node blah = new Node(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code already seems perfect. There are no new nodes created inside your function. Only two node-references (previous and current) are created which are sufficient and the logic is graceful :)